# Sitecore media item url

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am on Sitecore **7.2**

I am experiencing issues trying to retrieve media URL.

I have a template (`PageBanner`) with just one field called `BannerImage`. Field type is `Image`.

Another template named `Homepage` inherits this template `PageBanner`.

A content item `Home` uses template `Homepage`. I can see the `BannerImage` field as a part of the `Home` content item. An image has been assigned to this field as well.

Now, the back-end bit where the issue is encountered.

`homeItem.Field["BannerImage"]` returns image item.

[image]

`homeItem["BannerImage"]` returns empty string.

If I try to cast it to *ImageField* -`(ImageField)homeItem.Field["BannerImage"]`, the resultant ImageField item doesn't have `MediaItem` or any other field set.

I can do :

```
var imageFieldItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(homeItem.Fields["BannerImage"].ID);
var mediaUrl = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageFieldItem);
```

But that gives me a dynamic media url in the form of -`~/media/a2c15f35836746f398e772c81d040607.ashx`

I am looking to get the media URL by path.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: What's the value of `homeItem["BannerImage"]` without `.Fields`?

Comment: It returns Image item. I will add some debug info to the question @MarekMusielak

Comment: @NomadTravaler it will never return an Image item. The only thing it can return is a string. What is the value of the string? Is this an xml? Is this a string with item guid? Something else? What you wrote is **with** `.Fields`

Comment: My bad @MarekMusielak. Din't read your comment right. It returned an empty string.

Comment: It means that there is a field, but it has no value. Go to Sitecore Desktop (`/sitecore/shell` url) and find the home item. See what's the value of the field there.

Comment: I have added an image as its value. Checked the raw value of the field too. Media is assigned to it. And this is why I get the dynamic URL back.

Comment: Find the item with id `a2c15f35836746f398e772c81d040607` in your database. It's not image. It's the field, isn't it? Your trying to create a media link to the field item, not to the media item. For some reason your field has empty value in the `web` database.

Comment: Are all the relevant items and templates published?

Comment: Hi @MarekMusielak and Soren - yes, all the items have been published and I can see the fields populated in the web database

Comment: Is the linked media item published?

Answer (score 2):

You are making the correct call to get the URL using the `MediaManager` but you need to pass the inner MediaItem to the `GetMediaUrl()` method:

```
string imageURL = string.Empty;
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imageField = homeItem.Field["BannerImage"];
if (imageField != null && imageField.MediaItem != null)
{
    Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem image = new Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem(imageField.MediaItem);
    imageURL = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(image));
}
```

As for the dynamic URL being generated, if it is in Edit mode then this is normal, Check in Normal mode that the media URL is fully rendered.

Comment: Hi @jammykam. Like mentioned in the question. MediaItem field is null when I cast the `homeItem.Field["BannerImage"]` to ImageField.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code out in some utility class.

var imageUrl = GetImageUrl(homeItem, "BannerImage" false);

```
    public static string GetImageUrl(Item item, string fieldname, bool includeServerUrl)
    {
        // do the checks
        if (item == null) { return ""; }
        if (fieldname.Length == 0) { return ""; }

        // create media options
        Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions mediaUrlOptions = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions { AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true };
        mediaUrlOptions.AbsolutePath = true;

        // do we want to include the FQDN?
        if (includeServerUrl)
            mediaUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;

        // convert to image field
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imagefield = item.Fields[fieldname];

        if (imagefield == null) { return ""; }

        // get the item so we can process it
        Item mediaitem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(imagefield.MediaID);
        if (mediaitem == null) { return ""; }

        // pass in the item with the options to get the URL
        string mediaurl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaitem, mediaUrlOptions);
        if (mediaurl == null) { return ""; }

        return mediaurl;
    }
```